# How to validate SSL Certificate for Web request using ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, https, asp.net-core, self-signed, system.net.httpwebrequest

I had implemented a method for getting the response from a REST API request(SSL based one : `https://`) using APS.NET core (`System.Net.HttpWebRequest`).

I need to ignore the certificate error which occurred while getting the `WebResponse`. I referred many blogs and got a solution of using `ServicePointManager` and used this below code

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

But in ASP.NET core there is no support for `ServicePointManager`. So please help me to resolve this issue only by means of `HttpWebRequest` not by means of `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 4):

.NET Core makes the [ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler#System_Net_Http_HttpClientHandler_ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback) delegate available for you to override. Example:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
var http = new HttpClient(handler);
Console.WriteLine(http.GetAsync("https://expired.badssl.com/").GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```

Output:

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Server: nginx/1.10.0
  Server: (Ubuntu)
  Date: Mon, 06 Mar 2017 05:56:52 GMT
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  ETag: W/"58924b62-1d5"
  Cache-Control: no-store
  Content-Type: text/html
  Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Feb 2017 20:56:02 GMT
}
```

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 with .NET 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9728) related to this working the same on MacOS.

Comment: I had already referred this. But I want to know how to implement this for HttpWebRequest class.
For example:
`code`
string url="https://XXXXXXXX:XXXX";
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpRequest.Method = "Get";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
using (var result = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(httpRequest.BeginGetResponse, httpRequest.EndGetResponse, null)))
{
   StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(result.GetResponseStream());
   response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}

Comment: This looks like it will be possible in .NET Core 2.0 (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/16181).

Comment: HttpWebRequest is deprecated in .net core and just an additional layer on top of HttpClient.

Answer (score -1):

Before calling the request:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new   
RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(validarCertificado);
```

...And include this function:

```
protected bool validarCertificado(Object sender,
                              X509Certificate certificado,
                              X509Chain cadena,
                              SslPolicyErrors sslErrores)
{
   return true;
}
```